# Window padding in PUTTY in full screen

Tags: putty

I am trying to get window padding in full screen mode. A window padding option exists but it seems to loose it's effect when I switch to full screen. Any ideas?

[image: foo]

Answer (score 2):

this "feature" is known for long time, actually there was a bug report / feature request somewhere, but i could not find it anymore.

The best you can do right now is to check the option "sunken-edge border" in windows -> appearance (where you also can set the gap between text and window edge). This gives you maybe 3px gap:
[image]
left: fullscreen without sunken-edge border
right: fullscreen with sunken-edge border

meanwhile, you could send a feature request to the developer:
[http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/)

(just in case you are counfused about "KiTTY" in window title, KiTTY is a putty fork with local sesson storage instead of registry, which makes it portable and easy to backup)